# independent Poisson-distribution random variable

Tags: probability, independence, poisson-distribution

Let $V,W,Z$ independent Poisson($\lambda$)-distributed random variable. $\lambda>0$.
$X:=V+W, Y:=V+Z$

how can i show, that X and Y are independent?

Comment: I would be surprised if they were. If, say, $X=1000$, it makes it less likely that $V=0$, hence that $Y=0$.

Comment: Dumb question: $X$ and $Y$ both have $V$ in them so probably they aren't independent? Idk. Are there cases where you could have independence in a similar case?

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\c}{\operatorname{cov}}\newcommand{\v}{\operatorname{var}}$What would make you think they're independent?
\begin{align}
\c(X,Y) & = \c(V+W, V+Z) \\[10pt]
& = \c(V,V) + \c(V,Z) + \c(W,V) + \c(W,Z) \\[10pt]
& = \v(V)+0+0+0 \\[10pt]
& = \lambda+0+0+0 \\[10pt]
& = \lambda>0.
\end{align}